# printing special characters from char

Tags: java, special-characters, phone-number

I'm writing a program converts letters in a phone number into their corresponding digits, and it's almost complete aside from some formatting:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PhoneKeypad
{
   public static void main (String [] args)
   { 

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

String number;

      int currentChar;

      char character;

      int finalNumber;

      int getNumber;

      int start;

      String end;

currentChar = 0;

do
      {
         System.out.print ("\nEnter a phone number with letters: ");
         number = scan.nextLine();

         number = number.toUpperCase();

         while (currentChar < number.length())
         {
            character = number.charAt(currentChar);

            finalNumber = getNumber(character);

            System.out.print (finalNumber);

            currentChar++;
         }

         System.out.print ("\n\nContinue? <y/n> ");
         end = scan.next();

         System.out.flush();

         scan.nextLine(); 

         currentChar = 0;

      } while (!end.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));

   }

public static int getNumber (char uppercaseLetter)
   {
      int resultChar = 0;

      if (Character.isLetter(uppercaseLetter))
      {
         if (uppercaseLetter == 'A' || uppercaseLetter == 'B' || uppercaseLetter == 'C')
            resultChar = 2;

         else if (uppercaseLetter == 'D' || uppercaseLetter == 'E' || uppercaseLetter == 'F')
            resultChar = 3;

         else if (uppercaseLetter == 'G' || uppercaseLetter == 'H' || uppercaseLetter == 'I')
            resultChar = 4;

         else if (uppercaseLetter == 'J' || uppercaseLetter == 'K' || uppercaseLetter == 'L')
            resultChar = 5;

         else if (uppercaseLetter == 'M' || uppercaseLetter == 'N' || uppercaseLetter == 'O')
            resultChar = 6;

         else if (uppercaseLetter == 'P' || uppercaseLetter == 'Q' || uppercaseLetter == 'R' || uppercaseLetter == 'S')
            resultChar = 7;

         else if (uppercaseLetter == 'T' || uppercaseLetter == 'U' || uppercaseLetter == 'V')
            resultChar = 8;

         else if (uppercaseLetter == 'W' || uppercaseLetter == 'X' ||    uppercaseLetter == 'Y' || uppercaseLetter == 'Z')
            resultChar = 9;
      }   

      else if (Character.isDigit(uppercaseLetter))
      {
         resultChar = Character.getNumericValue(uppercaseLetter);
      }     

      return resultChar;        
   }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I need to print the phone number back out exactly as the user entered it, aside the the letters. If the user enters 1-800-flowers, the program needs to print it back out as 1-800-3569377. It's the same for any special characters - hyphens, spaces, parenthesis, etc.
And the simpler the solution, the better, as I haven't yet gotten to arrays or anything more complicated than methods.